# what is the cgi command for passing HTML form data?

Tags: php, html, cgi

What command will put a list of the CGI parameters passed from a HTML form along with there associated values into an array called $cgi_vars?

```
$cgi_vars = $_REQUEST;
$cgi_vars = $_CGI_VARIABLE;
$cgi_vars = get_env($HTTP_SERVER_VARS);
$cgi_vars = print_r($HTTP_SERVER_VARS);
```

Comment: None of those will do *only* that.

Comment: And since you are demanding an answer that is one of those four options … just **build a test script** and try it for yourself.

Comment: Hello Quentin, I'm not demanding, it is an interview question on a web based interview, I don't know much about CGI, I want to know to what is the answer from the options

Comment: If this is for an interview, then you should know the answer already.

Answer (score 0):

There's `$_GET` and `$_POST`, depending on what method you're using to submit the form. `$_REQUEST` works as well, but should be avoided because what you get out of it depends on PHP settings, and a mixed-mode submission (e.g.a  POST form but using query variables in the URL) is dependent on those settings.

So you'd have

```
$get_vars = $_GET;
$post_vars = $_POST;
```

but there's no reason to do this - the $_GET/POST arrays are superglobals and available anywhere in PHP. Your new variables are just normal variables and subject to the PHP scoping rules.

Comment: The below four are the options for the question, the answer should be from them.

Comment: As I said, $_REQUEST should be avoided. If you insist on using it, then don't complain later when things start mysteriously blowing up on you.

Answer (score 0):

`$_POST` contains POST data and `$_GET` contains data from the query string

Comment: Thank you DAVID, But the answer should be from below four options only

Comment: In that case, your best answer is `$cgi_vars = $_REQUEST;` but you still shouldn't use it in a production script.

Comment: Thank you DAVID, Thank you very much for your effort. I have searched for this question on the internet, There is nothing for this question, Once again thank you.